# How to fix this firebase error display message?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

When I run my app, this message always pops up:

```
2022-08-13 18:10:30.982952+0800 boomshakalakaProject[21996:10239330] 9.3.0 - [FirebaseInAppMessaging][I-IAM700002] Error happened during message fetching Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=403 "(null)"
2022-08-13 18:10:31.142422+0800 boomshakalakaProject[21996:10239328] [boringssl] boringssl_metrics_log_metric_block_invoke(153) Failed to log metrics
```

I did update my firebase package, and I didn't change any rules in my cloud firestore.

But the main issue is that after signing up an account using firebase, my app would crash and go to the breakpoint:

```
2022-08-13 18:25:43.907717+0800 boomshakalakaProject[22562:10256928] [Firebase/Crashlytics] Version 9.3.0
2022-08-13 18:25:43.946271+0800 boomshakalakaProject[22562:10257221] 9.3.0 - [FirebaseMessaging][I-FCM001000] FIRMessaging Remote Notifications proxy enabled, will swizzle remote notification receiver handlers. If you'd prefer to manually integrate Firebase Messaging, add "FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled" to your Info.plist, and set it to NO. Follow the instructions at:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client#method_swizzling_in_firebase_messaging
to ensure proper integration.
2022-08-13 18:25:43.946559+0800 boomshakalakaProject[22562:10257221] 9.3.0 - [GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler][I-SWZ001014] App Delegate does not conform to UIApplicationDelegate protocol.
2022-08-13 18:25:43.956369+0800 boomshakalakaProject[22562:10257219] [Client] Synchronous remote object proxy returned error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 3 - No such process." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 3 - No such process.}
2022-08-13 18:25:43.956396+0800 boomshakalakaProject[22562:10257214] [Client] Updating selectors failed with: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 3 - No such process." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 3 - No such process.}
2022-08-13 18:25:43.957587+0800 boomshakalakaProject[22562:10257214] [Client] Updating selectors failed with: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 3 - No such process." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 3 - No such process.}
2022-08-13 18:25:43.957651+0800 boomshakalakaProject[22562:10257214] [Client] Updating selectors after delegate addition failed with: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 3 - No such process." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 3 - No such process.}
2022-08-13 18:25:44.026019+0800 boomshakalakaProject[22562:10257221] 9.3.0 - [FirebaseAnalytics][I-ACS023007] Analytics v.9.3.0 started
2022-08-13 18:25:44.026173+0800 boomshakalakaProject[22562:10257221] 9.3.0 - 
2022-08-13 18:25:44.050713+0800 boomshakalakaProject[22562:10257214] [boringssl] boringssl_metrics_log_metric_block_invoke(153) Failed to log metrics
2022-08-13 18:25:44.337281+0800 boomshakalakaProject[22562:10257224] 9.3.0 - [FirebaseMessaging][I-FCM002022] APNS device token not set before retrieving FCM Token for Sender ID '564149306671'. Notifications to this FCM Token will not be delivered over APNS.Be sure to re-retrieve the FCM token once the APNS device token is set.
2022-08-13 18:25:44.337790+0800 boomshakalakaProject[22562:10257224] 9.3.0 - [FirebaseAnalytics][I-ACS800023] No pending snapshot to activate. SDK name: app_measurement
2022-08-13 18:25:44.362821+0800 boomshakalakaProject[22562:10257219] [boringssl] boringssl_metrics_log_metric_block_invoke(153) Failed to log metrics
2022-08-13 18:25:44.379574+0800 boomshakalakaProject[22562:10257223] 9.3.0 - [FirebaseAnalytics][I-ACS023012] Analytics collection enabled
2022-08-13 18:25:44.379780+0800 boomshakalakaProject[22562:10257223] 9.3.0 - [FirebaseAnalytics][I-ACS023220] Analytics screen reporting is enabled. Call Analytics.logEvent(AnalyticsEventScreenView, parameters: [...]) to log a screen view event. To disable automatic screen reporting, set the flag FirebaseAutomaticScreenReportingEnabled to NO (boolean) in the Info.plist
2022-08-13 18:26:14.498359+0800 boomshakalakaProject[22562:10257552] [boringssl] boringssl_metrics_log_metric_block_invoke(153) Failed to log metrics
fetching curr user...
2022-08-13 18:26:14.792686+0800 boomshakalakaProject[22562:10256928] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000035a7480 'BIB_Trailing_CB_Leading' H:[_UIModernBarButton:0x13c6b68b0]-(6)-[_UIModernBarButton:0x13c6bd910'Tasks']   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000035a74d0 'CB_Trailing_Trailing' _UIModernBarButton:0x13c6bd910'Tasks'.trailing <= _UIButtonBarButton:0x13c6bfa00.trailing   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000035a7de0 'UINav_static_button_horiz_position' _UIModernBarButton:0x13c6b68b0.leading == UILayoutGuide:0x600002fac7e0'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.leading   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000035a7e30 'UINavItemContentGuide-leading' H:[_UIButtonBarButton:0x13c6bfa00]-(6)-[UILayoutGuide:0x600002fae760'UINavigationBarItemContentLayoutGuide']   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000035a6530 'UINavItemContentGuide-trailing' UILayoutGuide:0x600002fae760'UINavigationBarItemContentLayoutGuide'.trailing == _UINavigationBarContentView:0x13c66da90.trailing   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000357fb60 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' _UINavigationBarContentView:0x13c66da90.width == 0   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000035a68f0 'UIView-leftMargin-guide-constraint' H:|-(8)-[UILayoutGuide:0x600002fac7e0'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'](LTR)   (active, names: '|':_UINavigationBarContentView:0x13c66da90 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000035a7480 'BIB_Trailing_CB_Leading' H:[_UIModernBarButton:0x13c6b68b0]-(6)-[_UIModernBarButton:0x13c6bd910'Tasks']   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2022-08-13 18:26:14.793818+0800 boomshakalakaProject[22562:10256928] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000035a7430 'BIB_Leading_Leading' H:|-(0)-[_UIModernBarButton:0x13c6b68b0]   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x13c6bfa00 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000035a7de0 'UINav_static_button_horiz_position' _UIModernBarButton:0x13c6b68b0.leading == UILayoutGuide:0x600002fac7e0'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.leading   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000035a7e30 'UINavItemContentGuide-leading' H:[_UIButtonBarButton:0x13c6bfa00]-(6)-[UILayoutGuide:0x600002fae760'UINavigationBarItemContentLayoutGuide']   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000035a6530 'UINavItemContentGuide-trailing' UILayoutGuide:0x600002fae760'UINavigationBarItemContentLayoutGuide'.trailing == _UINavigationBarContentView:0x13c66da90.trailing   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000357fb60 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' _UINavigationBarContentView:0x13c66da90.width == 0   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000035a68f0 'UIView-leftMargin-guide-constraint' H:|-(8)-[UILayoutGuide:0x600002fac7e0'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'](LTR)   (active, names: '|':_UINavigationBarContentView:0x13c66da90 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000035a7430 'BIB_Leading_Leading' H:|-(0)-[_UIModernBarButton:0x13c6b68b0]   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x13c6bfa00 )>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2022-08-13 18:26:14.794498+0800 boomshakalakaProject[22562:10256928] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000035a6fd0 UIView:0x13c6ba840.trailing == _UIBackButtonMaskView:0x13c6bdbf0.trailing   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000035a7a70 'Mask_Trailing_Trailing' _UIBackButtonMaskView:0x13c6bdbf0.trailing == _UIButtonBarButton:0x13c6bfa00.trailing   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000035a7bb0 'MaskEV_Leading_BIB_Trailing' H:[_UIModernBarButton:0x13c6b68b0]-(0)-[UIView:0x13c6ba840]   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000035a7de0 'UINav_static_button_horiz_position' _UIModernBarButton:0x13c6b68b0.leading == UILayoutGuide:0x600002fac7e0'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.leading   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000035a7e30 'UINavItemContentGuide-leading' H:[_UIButtonBarButton:0x13c6bfa00]-(6)-[UILayoutGuide:0x600002fae760'UINavigationBarItemContentLayoutGuide']   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000035a6530 'UINavItemContentGuide-trailing' UILayoutGuide:0x600002fae760'UINavigationBarItemContentLayoutGuide'.trailing == _UINavigationBarContentView:0x13c66da90.trailing   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000357fb60 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' _UINavigationBarContentView:0x13c66da90.width == 0   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000035a68f0 'UIView-leftMargin-guide-constraint' H:|-(8)-[UILayoutGuide:0x600002fac7e0'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'](LTR)   (active, names: '|':_UINavigationBarContentView:0x13c66da90 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000035a6fd0 UIView:0x13c6ba840.trailing == _UIBackButtonMaskView:0x13c6bdbf0.trailing   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
(lldb)
```

I literally have no idea what this means and I am really struggling. Sorry for any inconviences caused.

Before this I tried to configure my firebase by doing this:

```
 class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
//  func application(_ application: UIApplication,
//                   didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
//    FirebaseApp.configure()
//
//    return true
//  }
     
 }

@main
struct boomshakalakaProjectApp: App {
//    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var delegate
    
    @StateObject private var userManager = UserManager()
    @StateObject var focusClassModel: FocusClassModel = .init()
    
    init() {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
    }
    
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            MainView()
                .task {
                    userManager.checkIfUserIsSignedIn()
                }
                .environmentObject(userManager)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions. 

Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.

Comment: The code in the question is unclear; you've got code commented out and then other code showing; does the commented code cause the crash or the other code? Neither matches the the Firestore Getting Started Guide [Initialize Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#initialize). See that link and the the [AppDelegate.swift](https://github.com/firebase/snippets-ios/blob/8964f94fe68c6c2d05011f331a95e55f326f903e/firestore/swift/firestore-smoketest/AppDelegate.swift#L31-L33) link as well for guidance. Also, what version of XCode and Swift is it?

Comment: @Jay I believe it is the latest version. I had to delete some of the code because the system thinks im spamming... i commented some code out because i believe it is relevant to my app crashing situation but i dont know what  to do with it

Comment: Again, I know you want help you you're going to have to do the leg work yourself. The code in the question does not match the code on the Firebase getting started guide as linked above. Along with that you're AppDelegate just looks odd, and the compiler agrees **App Delegate does not conform to UIApplicationDelegate** - I don't know if you copy and pasted over the correct code or what but that's not generally how an iOS app would look. I suggest creating a new iOS App so you can see what's provided as the defauly AppDelegate.